# react-native linking firestack error

Tags: android, npm, react-native

I am trying to use firestack in my react-native application.
I did:

> npm install react-native-firestack --save

but then when I try to link:

> react-native link react-native-firestack

I get the error:

> rnpm-install ERR! It seems something went wrong while linking. Error: spawn UNKNOWN

Do you have any ideas why is this?

Comment: read android section of `https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-firestack` document.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding try this:

First use `rnpm link react-native-firestack`

if it does not work then try this:

You can remove these lines from package.json:

```
 "rnpm": {
    "commands": {
      "prelink": "node_modules/react-native-lock/bin/prepare.sh",
      "postlink": "node_modules/react-native-lock/bin/cocoapods.sh"
    }
  }
```